# Can I have attributes in an Angular directive which uses parent scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that uses the data from the parent scope. Now, I want to have an attribute in it, but still want to use the parent scope and not transfer all the other data in more attributes and duplicate objects.

```
var myDirective = function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: '/Areas/GetAdvice/Templates/Directives/loan-comparison-table-directive.html?1',
    //scope: - Don't add anything here to use the scope of the parent
    // But how to use an attribute in this way?
    controller: [
    '$scope',  function ($scope) {
        // Some Code
    }
}
```

So, how can I add an attribute (independent variable) in the directive, when having the parent scope inherited?

**EDIT:**
I want just a simple boolean property - something like isDescriptionVisible (true/false). The problem is that I use the same directive twice in my view, so I cannot have a variable in the parent scope, because it will affect both directives and I won't have control on them separately.

Comment: What you want in attribute?

Comment: Just a simple boolean property - something like isDescriptionVisible (true/false). The problem is that I use the same directive twice in my view, so I cannot have a variable in the parent scope, because it will affect both directives and I won't have control on them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an isolated scope for the directive. This is the exact use case for it. Otherwise you need to create separate variables to track the booleans in the parent scope.

If you don't need to pass boolean value from the parent scope you can do the following:

```
var myDirective = function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
templateUrl: '/Areas/GetAdvice/Templates/Directives/loan-comparison-table-directive.html?1',
scope: {}
controller: [
'$scope',  function ($scope) {
    $scope.isVisible = false;
}
}
```

If you need to pass it from the parent scope just simply replace

```
scope: {}
```

with

```
scope: {
isVisible: '='
}
```